# Attempt to invoke virtual method error causing app to close when performing given function

Tags: android, firebase

**My java code:**

```
public class PublishContentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    VideoView videoView;
    String type;
    Uri videoUri;

    MediaController mediaController;

    NachoTextView nachoTextView;
    TextView txt_upload;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_publish_content);

        nachoTextView = findViewById(R.id.input_video_tag);

        txt_upload = findViewById(R.id.txt_upload_video);

        videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        mediaController = new MediaController(PublishContentActivity.this);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        if(intent !=null){
            videoUri=intent.getData();
            videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
            videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
            videoView.start();
        }

        nachoTextView.addChipTerminator(',', ChipTerminatorHandler.BEHAVIOR_CHIPIFY_ALL);

        txt_upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(PublishContentActivity.this, "Tags :" +nachoTextView.getAllChips().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Error in following line:**

```
txt_upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(PublishContentActivity.this, "Tags :" +nachoTextView.getAllChips().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

**The error says the following:**

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: Are you sure `txt_upload_video` is on the `activity_publish_content` layout?

Comment: Show us the layout file.